# Amazon Web Services - Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

How to remove transfer lock for Registered Domain in AWS Route 53?

[image: AWS Domain Transfer Lock]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just login to the AWS Console, go to Route 53, on the left side look at Registered Domain, select the domain you want and once the domain details load. You should see a (enabled) hyperlink next to the Transfer Lock.